# In this assignment(Dat Structures). I get two errors, 1-Test BinarySearchTree.isBalanced() 2-Test BinarySearchTree.balance()

Tags: java, data-structures

In this assignment(Dat Structures). I get two errors, 1-Test BinarySearchTree.isBalanced() 2-Test BinarySearchTree.balance()

```
/**
 * Created by angjelinmalaj on 4/28/17.
 */
import java.util.Vector;


public class Driver implements DriverInterface {


    private TreeItem<Integer, String>[] treeItems;

    public Vector<TreeItem<Integer, String>> getVectorOfTreeItems() {

        Vector<TreeItem<Integer, String>> treeVector = new Vector<TreeItem<Integer, String>>();

        final int MAX_COUNT = 131071;
        //final int MAX_COUNT = 137071;


        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COUNT; i++)

        {

            int key = (int) ((int)i+10 * (Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)));

            String value = "String" + key;

            TreeItem<Integer, String> item = new TreeItem<Integer, String>(key, value);

            treeVector.add(item);

            //return treeVector;

        }

        return treeVector;
    }

    @Override
    public BinarySearchTree<Integer, String> createAndPopulateBST(Vector<TreeItem<Integer, String>> treeItems) {
        BinarySearchTree<Integer, String> tree = new BinarySearchTree<Integer, String>();

        for (TreeItem<Integer, String> treeItem : treeItems) {

            // add each tree item to BinarySearchTree
            tree.insert(treeItem);
        }


        return tree;
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Driver driver = new Driver();

        Vector<TreeItem<Integer, String>> treeItems = driver.getVectorOfTreeItems();

        BinarySearchTree<Integer, String> tree = driver.createAndPopulateBST(treeItems);
        System.out.println("Height of the Binary Search Tree : " + tree.height());

        tree.balance();
        System.out.println("Height of the Binary Search Tree after Balancing : " + tree.height());


    }
}
```

BinarySearchTree class

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class BinarySearchTree <K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> extends Vector<TreeItem<Integer, String>> {

    private TreeNode<K, V> root;

    /**
     * Default constructor for BinarySearchTree. This constructor instantiates
     * an empty tree
     */
    public BinarySearchTree() {
        this.root = null;
    }


    /**
     * This constructor instantiates a BinarySearchTree with the given <code>root</code>
     *
     * @param root The root TreeNode for this BinarySearchTree
     */
    public BinarySearchTree(TreeNode<K, V> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }


    /**
     * Method to get the current root of this BinarySearchTree
     *
     * @return The root TreeNode for this BinarySearchTree
     */
    public TreeNode<K, V> getRoot() {
        return root;
    }


    /**
     * Method to set set the root of this BinarySearchTree
     *
     * @param root The new root of this BinarySearchTree
     */
    public void setRoot(TreeNode<K, V> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }


    /**
     * Method to get the <b>TreeItem</b> currently in the root of this BinarySearchTree
     *
     * @return Returns the <b>TreeItem</b> currently in the root
     * @throws TreeException Throws a <b>TreeException</b> if the root of the tree is <b>null</b>
     */
    public TreeItem<K, V> getRootItem() throws TreeException {
        if (this.root == null) {
            throw new TreeException("TreeException: Tree Is Empty, No Root Item");
        } else {
            return this.root.getTreeItem();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Method to find out if the BinarySearchTree is empty
     *
     * @return Returns <b>true</b> if the root in <b>null</b>, otherwise, returns <b>false</b>
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (root == null);
    }


    /**
     * Method to remove all entries from the BinarySearchTree.
     */
    public void makeEmpty() {
        this.root = null;
    }


    /**
     * Method to find and retrieve the <b>TreeItem</b>
     * with the given <b>key</b> if it is in the BinarySearchTree.
     *
     * @param key The <b>key</b> that the user wishes to search for
     * @return The <b>TreeItem</b> with the given <b>key</b> if found. Otherwise, returns
     * <b>null</b>
     */
    public TreeItem<K, V> find(K key) {
        return findItem(this.root, key);
    }


    /**
     * The <b>private recursive</b> method to find and retrieve  the <b>TreeItem</b>
     * with the given <b>key</b> if it is in the BinarySearchTree. This method is initially
     * called by the {@link #find <b><u>find</u></b>} method
     *
     * @param node The current TreeNode being searched
     * @param key  The <b>key</b> that the user wishes to search for
     * @return The <b>TreeItem</b> with the given <b>key</b> if found. Otherwise, returns
     * <b>null</b>
     */
    private TreeItem<K, V> findItem(TreeNode<K, V> node, K key) {
        if (node == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (node.getTreeItem().getKey().compareTo(key) == 0) {
            return node.getTreeItem();
        } else if (node.getTreeItem().getKey().compareTo(key) > 0) {
            return findItem(node.getLeftChild(), key);
        } else {
            return findItem(node.getRightChild(), key);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Method to insert the given <b>TreeItem</b> into the BinarySearchTree
     *
     * @param treeItem The <b>TreeItem</b> to insert into the BinarySearchTree
     */
    public void insert(TreeItem<K, V> treeItem) {
        this.root = insertItem(this.root, null, treeItem);
    }


    /**
     * The <b>private recursive</b> method to insert the <b>TreeItem</b>
     * into the BinarySearchTree. This method is initially
     * called by the {@link #insert <b><u>insert</u></b>} method
     *
     * @param node     The current TreeNode being examined for insertion
     * @param parent   The current parent of the TreeNode being examined
     * @param treeItem The <b>TreeItem</b> to insert into the BinarySearchTree
     * @return The node that existed or was inserted into the BinarySearchTree
     */
    private TreeNode<K, V> insertItem(TreeNode<K, V> node, TreeNode<K, V> parent, TreeItem<K, V> treeItem) {
        if (node == null) {
            node = new TreeNode<K, V>(treeItem);
            node.setParent(parent);
        } else if (node.getTreeItem().getKey().compareTo(treeItem.getKey()) > 0) {
            node.setLeftChild(this.insertItem(node.getLeftChild(), node, treeItem));
        } else {
            node.setRightChild(this.insertItem(node.getRightChild(), node, treeItem));
        }

        return node;
    }


    /**
     * This is the public method used to delete a TreeItem from the <code>BinarySearchTree</code> based
     * on the specified <b>key</b>.
     *
     * @param key The <b>key</b> of the TreeItem the user wishes to delete from the <code>BinarySearchTree</code>.
     */
    public void delete(K key) throws TreeException {
        setRoot(deleteItem(getRoot(), key));
    }   // end delete


    /**
     * The <b>private recursive</b> method to delete the <b>TreeItem</b>
     * with the specified <b>key</b> from BinarySearchTree. This method is initially
     * called by the {@link #delete <b><u>delete</u></b>} method
     *
     * @param node The current TreeNode being examined for deletion
     * @param key  The <b>key</b> of the TreeItem to be deleted
     * @return The TreeNode reference that will replace the deleted TreeNode
     */
    private TreeNode<K, V> deleteItem(TreeNode<K, V> node, K key) {

        if (node == null) {
            throw new TreeException("TreeException:  Item not found");
        } else {
            TreeItem<K, V> treeItem = node.getTreeItem();
            if (key.compareTo(treeItem.getKey()) == 0) {
                // item is in this node, which is the root of a subtree
                node = deleteNode(node);   // delete the item
            } else if (key.compareTo(treeItem.getKey()) < 0) {
                // search the left subtree
                node.setLeftChild(deleteItem(node.getLeftChild(), key));
            } else {
                // search the right subtree
                node.setRightChild(deleteItem(node.getRightChild(), key));
            } // end if
        } // end if
        return node;
    } // end deleteItem


    /**
     * The <b>private recursive</b> method to delete the specified <b>TreeNode</b>.
     * There are four cases to consider:
     * <ol>
     * <li>The node is a leaf: just remove the node.</li>
     * <li>The node has no left child: replace the node with it's right child</li>
     * <li>The node has no right child: replace the node with it's left child</li>
     * <li>The node has two children: find the in-order successor, swap TreeItems and delete the successor</li>
     * </ol>
     * This method is initally called by the {@link #deleteItem <b><u>deleteItem</u></b>} method
     *
     * @param node The current TreeNode being examined for deletion
     * @return The TreeNode reference that will replace the deleted TreeNode
     */
    private TreeNode<K, V> deleteNode(TreeNode<K, V> node) {
        if ((node.getLeftChild() == null) && (node.getRightChild() == null)) {
            // node is a leaf
            return null;
        } else if (node.getLeftChild() == null) {
            // no left child
            return node.getRightChild();
        } else if (node.getRightChild() == null) {
            // no right child
            return node.getLeftChild();
        } else {
            // there are two children:
            TreeNode<K, V> successorNode;
            successorNode = findLeftmost(node.getRightChild());
            node.setRightChild(deleteLeftmost(node.getRightChild()));
            return node;
        }   // end if
    }   // end deleteNode


    /**
     * The <b>private recursive</b> method to find the left-most child of a subtree
     * This method is initially called by the {@link #deleteNode <b><u>deleteNode</u></b>} method
     *
     * @param node The current TreeNode being examined for being the left-most child
     * @return The TreeNode reference that is the left-most child
     */
    private TreeNode<K, V> findLeftmost(TreeNode<K, V> node) {
        if (node.getLeftChild() == null) {
            return node;
        } else {
            return findLeftmost(node.getLeftChild());
        }   // end if
    }   // end findLeftmost


    /**
     * The <b>private recursive</b> method to deleted the left-most child of a subtree
     * This method is initially called by the {@link #deleteNode <b><u>deleteNode</u></b>} method
     *
     * @param node The current TreeNode being examined for being the left-most child
     * @return The TreeNode reference that is the left-most child
     */
    private TreeNode<K, V> deleteLeftmost(TreeNode<K, V> node) {
        if (node.getLeftChild() == null) {
            return node.getRightChild();
        } else {
            node.setLeftChild(deleteLeftmost(node.getLeftChild()));
            return node;
        }   // end if
    }// end deleteLeftmost

    // This method is used to obtain the height of the BinarySearchTree.
    public int height() {

        // call the private recursive method
        return treeHeight(root);
    }


//The recursive helper method

    // The private recursive method to calculate the height of a subtree rooted at the specified TreeNode
    private int treeHeight(TreeNode<K, V> node) {


//Here, if  the node is null height is 0 (Base case of recursion.

        // empty node, means no height
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        }


//Otherwise, we get the left and right height. Then we return the greater one :

        else {
            // get height of left subtree (with recursion)
            int leftHeight = treeHeight(node.getLeftChild());

            // get height of right subtree (with recursion)
            int rightHeight = treeHeight(node.getRightChild());

            // return the bigger height
            // make sure to add +1 for the height of the current node
            if (leftHeight > rightHeight)
                return (leftHeight + 1);
            else
                return (rightHeight + 1);
        }
    }


//The next method is isBalanced(). Here, we also have a recursive helper.


//So the method itself is :

    // This is the method the user calls to find out if the BinarySearchTree is balanced.
    public boolean isBalanced() {
        // call the private recursive method
        return isBalancedSubtree(root);
    }


//The recursive helper method


    // The private recursive method to determine if the subtree rooted at the given node is balanced
    private boolean isBalancedSubtree(TreeNode<K, V> node) {

//This will also need some help from the previous height methods. We start by getting left-right heights :

        // get height of left subtree (with treeHeight method)
        int leftHeight = treeHeight(node.getLeftChild());

        // get height of right subtree (with treeHeight method)
        int rightHeight = treeHeight(node.getRightChild());


//Now, the height difference :

        // obtain the left-right height difference
        int heightDifference = leftHeight - rightHeight;


//This should only be -1, 0, or 1 for balance

        // height difference can be a max of 1 (on left side or right side)
        if (heightDifference == -1 || heightDifference == 0 || heightDifference == 1) {
            // check subtree height balance on both and right child
            if (isBalancedSubtree(node.getLeftChild()) && isBalancedSubtree(node.getRightChild()))
                // when all success, return true
                return true;
        }


//And recursively we also check if left and right subtrees are balanced.


//If the conditions fail, then we return false:


        // not found, return false
        return false;
    }

    public void balance() {
        TreeIterator<K, V> it = new TreeIterator<K, V>((this));
        it.setInorder();

        int count = it.size();

        java.lang.Object[] arr = new Object[count];


        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            arr[i] = it.next();
        root = balanceTree(arr, 0, count - 1);
    }

    private TreeNode<K, V> balanceTree(Object[] arr, int first, int last) {

        if (first > last)
            return null;

        int center = (first+last)/2;
        TreeItem<K,V> item = (TreeItem<K,V>)arr[center];

        //now the construct left and right subtree

        TreeNode<K,V> node = new TreeNode<K,V>(item);
        node.setLeftChild(balanceTree(arr, first, center-1));
        node.setRightChild(balanceTree(arr, center+1, last));

        return node;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the link to my assignment, bc it does not allow me to put the whole text.
http://comet.lehman.cuny.edu/sfakhouri/teaching/cmp/cmp338/s17/hw/hw5.html

Answer (score 0):

The question is :
You will be instantiating a BinarySearchTree with TreeItem objects. Your tree will be expected to properly handle the following test cases:

Create 131,071 TreeItem objects randomly generated. Save all your randomly generated TreeItem objects in a Vector>.
Insert all your TreeItem objects into the BinarySearchTree.
Measure the height of the BinarySearchTree.
Balance the BinarySearchTree.